# php, mysql - Select row that have a column with multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I have the following kind of setup (a bit oversimplified):

An array (php): array('a', 'b', 'c');

Table 1: `id` with values (1), (2), (3), (others).

Table 2: `id`, `idT1`,`value` with values (1, 1, 'a'), (2, 1, 'b'), (3, 1, 'c'), (4, 2, 'c'), (5, 77, 'w') (others).

I need to select rows from table 1, that have correspondent in table 2 with ALL the values in the array (in this case the row with id col = 1).

A way to do this would be something like (ignore possible typos pls)

```
 <?php
      $query = "SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `id` IN ";
      $subqr = "";
      foreach ($arr as $a) {
          if (!$subqr)
              $subqr = "(SELECT `idT1` FROM `table2` WHERE `value` = '$a')";
          else
              $subqr .= " AND `id` IN (SELECT `idT1` FROM `table2` WHERE `value` = '$a')";
      }

      ExecuteQuery($query.$subqr); // Where ExecuteQuery gets query as param.
```

Now my problem is that... I'm not exactly comfortable with the solution... I mean... a foreach that adds subqueries is likely not to be the best approach. If the array has 9999 elements... 9999 subqueries would just kill mysql. Also bear in mind that this is oversimplified.

Any other ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, you want to select all the records from **Table 1** which has it's **ID** on **Table 2** on field **idT1**. If that's the case you can try

```
SELECT id
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.id=table2.idT1;
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.id=table2.idT1
WHERE table2.value IN ('a','b','c')
GROUP BY table1.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT table2.value) = 3
```

so first, you need to use php **implode** the array for the line

```
WHERE table2.value IN ('a','b','c')
```

then php **count** for this line

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT table2.value) = 3
```

that would replace 3

Comment: Not voting down, but you got it a bit wrong... I need to get all records from t1, that have corresponding rows in t2, that have values put together totaling that array... Is a bit tricky-er to explain...

Comment: ...apart from the SQL injection issue?

Comment: Don't care about injection at this point, the solution is valid to a point, that being that I didn't specify the array may not have distinct elements (didn't occur to me at that point). Doesn't exactly solve my problem but is a start, I can get it going from here so... +1.

Comment: @symcbean well yeah, I was answering assuming that zozo already know how to avoid SQL injection :)

Comment: Yeah... that's not a problem.